# How to return data with Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, npm, axios

I am trying to extract data from an Axios call in Javascript. I can see that the data is being called successfully if I console.log() while inside of this block

Here is a link to a screenshot of console.log() if it is inside the axios call. https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxlz8.jpg

This data is correct, but I can't access it outside of the axios call.

```
   const response = await axios
        .get(url, config)
        .then(function(response) {
          data = response.data;
          console.log(data)
        })
```

However, I am unable to do anything with the data outside of the getRide_Uber function. How do I extract the response object to use in other parts of my code?

```
const axios = require("axios");

// Use the Uber API to estimate the cost between two
// locations specified via latitude and longitude coordinates.

getRide_Uber = async (addressOrigin, addressDestination) => {
  let origin = await geocodeAddress(addressOrigin);
  let destination = await geocodeAddress(addressDestination);

  const url = "https://api.uber.com/v1.2/estimates/price";

  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Token ${process.env.UBER_SERVER_TOKEN}`
    },
    params: {
      start_latitude: origin.lat,
      start_longitude: origin.lon,
      end_latitude: destination.lat,
      end_longitude: destination.lon
    }
  };

  const response = await axios
    .get(url, config)
    .then(function(response) {
      data = response.data;
      return data;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  return response;
};

// Initial code
// const rideData = getRide_Uber("Arlington Texas", "Fort Worth Texas");
// const ridePrices = rideData.prices;
// console.log(ridePrices);

// Code suggestion by @mralanlee
const a = (async() => {
 const result = await getRide_Uber(start, dest);
 return result;
})();

console.log(a); // Console just says <pending>
const prices = a.prices // undefined
```

Please let me know if anything needs clarification and I will be happy to explain. Thanks!

Comment: `getRide_Uber` will continue the data if it is executed. so if i did something like `const a = getRide_Uber(start, dest);` then a will have the response data, since you are returning it.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "unable to do anything with the data" ? Could you add an example call of getRide_Uber ?

Comment: Hello @thibpat I have added an example call and also added a link to a console screenshot of the desired data. By unable to do anything with the data I mean that the data I try to pull from this function is undefined. So whenever I console.log(prices) I get undefined instead of an array. I also can't go any deeper into the object, so if I type rideDistance = rideData.prices[0].distance; The program will throw an error.

Comment: Hello @mralanlee I have added the proposed change and the data comes out as undefined. Do you have any ideas as to why this happens? Thanks

Comment: You don't `await` for `getRide` to complete.

Comment: Hey Christian, you will need to wrap it in in an async function and like @Nit says, you need to `await` it like... `const a = await getRide_Uber(start, dest)`, I'll submit an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data store is back into `getRide_Uber`.

You can have it accessible or returned globally like:

```
(async() => {
 const result = await getRide_Uber(start, dest);
 // or console.log(result)
 return result;
})()
```

or

```
const a = (async() => {
     const result = await getRide_Uber(start, dest);
     return result;
})();
```

For the above solution, you would need to have this in a scape of another `async` function. This will not work at the global level because logging the result will not wait for the `Promise` to resolve. You must wrap it into an `async` function and await the anonymous function.

Edit: Clarification to add more clarity...

To use the 2nd solution, you could do the following:

```
// this async function wraps around your code, we'll call it something for a lack of a better name
// start and dest params are passed into getRide_Uber
async function something(start, dest) {
  const result = await getRide_Uber(start, dest);
  // You can make sure you have the resolved data here.
  // console.log(result.prices)
  return result;
};

// now call the function
something(start, dest);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me @mralanlee. I am using `const a = (async() => {
     const result = await getRide_Uber(start, dest);
     return result;
})();` and when I console.log(a); The console just says <pending> and then returns nothing. If I then try prices = a.prices I get undefined still. What am I missing?

Comment: I also added your suggestion to my question to show how I am implementing it to see if the error is there. Thanks again for helping me look into this issue.

Comment: @ChristianGentry the problem is that it's not wrapper in an `async` function, so you're not waiting for the `Promise` to resolve at the global level. I'll edit my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: Thanks @mralanlee! This helps me understand this concept a lot better. You have been very helpful